# Multiple web sites or multiple web applications in IIS6?

Tags: asp.net, iis-6

Assuming that each app has its own app pool and that I have an unlimited number of domains/IPs handy, are there benefits to hosting applications as separate web sites as opposed to one site containing multiple applications?

Comment: I don't see a relation with this Q and programming in general. I think it's better to put this at ServerFault, where the web administrators are playing... :-)

Comment: This is an issue that developers have to deal with every day - if somebody wanted to post their question on another site I'm sure they would have done so.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Off the top of my head:

1. It's easier to manage/stop/start individual sites than applications under an existing site.
2. If you accidentally change the root web.config you could end up having unintended consequences in the child applications.
3. Ditto for IIS configuration changes in IIS Manager.
4. You'd have difficulty actually limiting the applications by domain name/ip address - you'd have to do your host filtering in code across all applications, while with individual sites you can explicitly point different domains at isolated applications (you only need multiple IPs if you're using SSL for them all).